# SearchView Не работает Русская раскладка клавиатуры

Tags: android, listview, android-search-view

Проблема в следующем как только запускаю приложение и в SearchView буквы на английской раскладке буквы вводятся отлично но как только переключаюсь на русскую вместо букв появляются цифры

```
public class WordsActivity1 extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
SearchView searchView;

String[]words1 = {"Машины","ТВ","PC","Интернет"};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_words1);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listview);
    searchView = (SearchView)findViewById(R.id.searchView);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
            (this,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,words1);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String text) {
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String text) {

            adapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            return false;
        }
    });


}
```

}

Comment: Тэг `SearchView` из разметки?

Comment: да searchview из разметки

Comment: Я имею ввиду добавьте его в вопрос